# Where should I ask questions about broken or not yet written code when there isn't an actual good question to be asked?

Tags: support, questions

I'm not quite sure where to ask for help on my code. For example, if I wanted to know why a certain function doesn't work and I had no clue why it didn't work, therefore not having a good question to ask on Stack Overflow, where or how should I ask for help? Earlier today I asked a question on Code Review, as I thought that's the place to ask, but I got told that it's the wrong place to ask for help for broken code or unwritten code.

Comment: If you don't have a good question, then why would you be able to ask it *anywhere*? If you have a function that doesn't work, try debugging it (see e.g. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and if you still can't crack it you should at least be able to cut it down to a good, specific question.

Comment: Create a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you haven't written the code yet, how do you even know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 7):

A question about broken logic in code ("why a certain function doesn't work") without accompanying code is going to be off-topic on Stack Overflow and all Stack Exchange network sites.

> not having a good question to ask on stackoverflow.com

If it's not a good question for SO, then you definitely shouldn't ask it there.

> i asked a question on codereview as i thought thats the place to ask i got told that its the wrong place to ask for help for broken code or unwritten code.

Right. Code Review is for code *review* - analysis of existing, working code to improve it and spot subtle problems. You can't review something that doesn't exist.

It's pretty much impossible to tell you why your function's logic is broken without code or at least pseudocode. A question like that is probably not going to be received well *anywhere*, much less on Stack Overflow. So, you shouldn't ask it here. And frankly, if there is a site that *would* accept a question like that, I wouldn't hold my breath for anything resembling a useful answer.